# Is the traditional character for 雪 the same as itself?

Tags: characters, traditional-vs-simplified

Is [image] the traditional character for http://screenshoot.me/XeEw1S?

Or are both [image] and http://screenshoot.me/XeEw1S considered the *same* character (汉字) with simply different font styles?

Answer (score 10):

These are 2 different fonts for the same character. There are many website to check that, see [this post](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1839/540) for an overview.

For example on [chineseetymology.org](http://www.chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?submitButton1=Etymology&characterInput=%E9%9B%AA) and [chinese-characters.org](http://chinese-characters.org/meaning/9/96EA.html#.USdiEqVwp8E) you can see that the simplified and traditional characters are identical (the former website explicitely writes: no simplification).

Having said this. Although they are considered to be the same character, people in different regions/countries have habits and the most common way to write something might be different and people might consider some variants as being wrong. This can be seen in the picture below (source [zdic.net](http://www.zdic.net/zd/zi/ZdicE9Zdic9BZdicAA.htm)):

[image: 雪in different countries]

Comment: But surely if you in mainland china, and you write 雪 with the tail sticking out, that will be considered wrong by the *standards* over there right?

Comment: Yes, most people would consider it wrong.

Comment: hmm, then how can we still say that they are the same 汉字?

Comment: @Pacerier. I consider they are the same character(not the same shape) since they are only different in fonts. They are differnt in the shape not because they are in traditional or simplified form,but because differnt standard forms are adopted. The difference has nothing to do the simplification.

Comment: @Pacerier They're 異體字, so they are the same...